# How to send icmpv6 Router Advertisement messages from an Android device

Tags: android, networking, ipv6, icmp, radvd

Some time ago I implemented a radvd daemon in a linux device in order to send icmpv6 Router Advertisement messages to its tethered devices. 
I took the radvd version 1.9.2 from this site: [http://www.litech.org/radvd/](http://www.litech.org). I compiled and installed it and wrote a small module to manage it (launch radvd daemon, define radvd configuration file according to device settings, etc.)

I am looking for doing the same in an Android device with Nougat version. I assume that the device properly received an IPv6 address from the system. 
So far I founded radvd version 1.8.5 for Android in this site: https://github.com/ddrown/android_external_radvd.

Is it a good version to start with in Android or does someone know a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enabled bluetooth tethering on one Android Phone and connected Another Android Phone using Bluetooth. I could observe that the tether enabled Android phone was capable of sending router advertisement. The Phone on which i enabled bluetooth tethering was connected to a mobile network that gave it an IPv6 address. So I dont think there is any need of a seperate radvd but I am not sure yet on which module on Android is helping to send router advertisement probably dnsmasq*

Above exercise helped me to know that Android has the capability of sending router advertisement without the need for installation of another module.

Comment: Yes you are right. The ability of sending router advertisement was introduced  in Google  some time ago. I probably tested it with an older version.

Comment: What version is required?